# Jquery mobile page shows previously viewed data

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building a JQM/Phonegap app and have an anoying issue.

I have a page that displays data from a websql/sqllite db, just 2-3 fields (#view?id=123). The first time you view this page, all works fine (I grab the data and add the values to the fields within the JQM pagebeforeshow event).

The issue arrise if you view the page again for a different record (#view?id=234). It shows the page with the last seen data and then after about 1-2 seconds updates it to the values for the current record.

Is there any way to stop this page from caching (is that the issue - I'm not using any of the JQM caching data attributes) or should I attempt to empty the fields on the pagehide event?

Thanks in advance.

Example code as discussed:

```
$('#view').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data) {

    // Clear any interval counter 
    clearInterval(window.viewTimerIntervalID);

    // On page load get passed url vars
    if ($.mobile.pageData && ($.mobile.pageData.caseRef || $.mobile.pageData.id)){
        if ($.mobile.pageData.caseRef) {
            $('input#edit-case-ref').val($.mobile.pageData.caseRef);
        }
        if ($.mobile.pageData.id) {
            $('input#edit-recordId').val($.mobile.pageData.id)
        }
    }

    // Grab record ID from hidden field
    var editId = $('input#edit-recordId').val();

    // form fields
    var caseTypeSelect = $('select#edit-case-type-select'),
        taskTypeSelect = $('select#edit-task-type-select'),
        caseRef = $('input#edit-case-ref'),
        notes = $('textarea#edit-notes'),
        editTimer = $('#edit-time h1'),
        startButton = $('#editStartStopRecording'),
        findCaseRef = $('a#findCaseRef');
    var startButtonTextSpan = $('#editStartStopRecording').prev('span').find('span.ui-btn-text');
    startButton.button('refresh');


    // Empty values of fields
    caseTypeSelect.val([]);
    taskTypeSelect.val([]);
    caseRef.val('');
    notes.val('');
    editTimer.text("0:00:00");


    // Get options for first select
    function getCaseTypes(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CASETYPES', [],
            function(tx,results){
                var len = results.rows.length;

                // Remove any options already appended.
                $('select#edit-case-type-select option').remove();

                // Cache CaseType Select
                var caseTypeSelect = $('select#edit-case-type-select');

                // Append the first empty blank value option
                caseTypeSelect.append('<option value="" data-placeholder="true">Select Case Type</option');

                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    // Append Select with details
                    caseTypeSelect.append('<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).id +'">' + results.rows.item(i).description + '</option>');
                }

                // Refresh the list to add JQM styles etc
                caseTypeSelect.trigger("change");
            },
            errorCB
        );
    }

    // Get options for second select
    function getTaskTypes(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ACTIONTYPES', [],
            function(tx,results){
                var len = results.rows.length;

                // Remove any options already appended.
                $('select#edit-task-type-select option').remove();

                // Cache CaseType Select
                var taskTypeSelect = $('select#edit-task-type-select');

                // Append the first empty blank value option
                taskTypeSelect.append('<option value="" data-placeholder="true">Select Task Type</option');

                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

                    // Append Select with details
                    taskTypeSelect.append('<option value="' + results.rows.item(i).id +'">' + results.rows.item(i).description + '</option>');
                }

                // Refresh the list to add JQM styles etc
                taskTypeSelect.trigger("change");
            },
            errorCB
        );
    }

    // populate the selects with values from DB
    function getRecording(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM RECORDINGS WHERE id=?', [editId],
            function(tx,results){
                var len = results.rows.length;

                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

                    // Add values to selects
                    caseTypeSelect.val(results.rows.item(i).caseTypeId);
                    taskTypeSelect.val(results.rows.item(i).actionTypeId);

                    // Store this start date as a global var
                    window.editStartDate = results.rows.item(i).startDate;

                    // Add value to inputs
                    caseRef.val(results.rows.item(i).caseRef);

                    // Add notes
                    notes.val(results.rows.item(i).notes);

                    // Refresh the list to add JQM styles etc
                    caseTypeSelect.trigger("change");
                    taskTypeSelect.trigger("change");

                    // Calculate the time if still recording and start timer
                    if (!results.rows.item(i).endDate) {

                        // No end date so still recording....
                        // Need to work out diff between start and now
                        // And increment

                        var start = new Date(results.rows.item(i).startDate);
                        var end = new Date();
                        var dateDiff =  end.getTime() - start.getTime();

                        milliSecs = dateDiff

                        // 1000 milliseconds in a second
                        msSecs = (1000)
                        // Convert to seconds
                        msMins = (msSecs * 60)
                        // Convert to mins
                        msHours = (msMins * 60)
                        // Floor and calc to hours
                        numHours = Math.floor(milliSecs/msHours)
                        // Calc Mins
                        numMins = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours)) / msMins)
                        // Calc secs 
                        numSecs = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours) - (numMins * msMins))/ msSecs)
                        // Add leading zeros
                        if (numSecs < 10){
                          numSecs = "0" + numSecs
                        }
                        if (numMins < 10){
                          numMins = "0" + numMins
                        }

                        // Calc results
                        timeOnLoad = numHours + ":" + numMins + ":" + numSecs;

                        // Add to timer
                        editTimer.text(timeOnLoad);

                        // Start the incrementor and put the incrementor id in a global var (wuldnt work inside a local var for some reason).
                        window.viewTimerIntervalID = setInterval(editCount,1000);

                        // Change the button
                        startButtonTextSpan.text('Pause');
                        startButton.buttonMarkup({theme: 'g'}); //Red
                        startButton.buttonMarkup({icon: 'minus'}); // Swap out for custom icons

                        // Add the stop class
                        startButton.addClass('stop');

                        // Disable all fields as still recording
                        caseTypeSelect.selectmenu('disable');
                        taskTypeSelect.selectmenu('disable');
                        caseRef.textinput('disable');
                        notes.textinput('disable');
                        findCaseRef.addClass('ui-disabled');


                    // Calculate the time if enddate exists
                    } else {

                        // There is an end time - so calc diff and append
                        // Get start and end date, convert to JS date objects and subtract
                        var start = new Date(results.rows.item(i).startDate);
                        var end = new Date(results.rows.item(i).endDate);
                        var dateDiff =  end.getTime() - start.getTime();

                        milliSecs = dateDiff

                        // 1000 milliseconds in a second
                        msSecs = (1000)
                        // Convert to seconds
                        msMins = (msSecs * 60)
                        // Convert to mins
                        msHours = (msMins * 60)
                        // Floor and calc to hours
                        numHours = Math.floor(milliSecs/msHours)
                        // Calc Mins
                        numMins = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours)) / msMins)
                        // Calc secs 
                        numSecs = Math.floor((milliSecs - (numHours * msHours) - (numMins * msMins))/ msSecs)
                        // Add leading zeros
                        if (numSecs < 10){
                          numSecs = "0" + numSecs
                        }
                        if (numMins < 10){
                          numMins = "0" + numMins
                        }

                        // Calc results
                        resultString = numHours + ":" + numMins + ":" + numSecs;

                        // Append data
                        editTimer.text(resultString);

                        // Change the button
                        startButtonTextSpan.text('Resume');
                        startButton.buttonMarkup({theme: 'f'}); //Green
                        startButton.buttonMarkup({icon: 'plus'});

                        // Add the stop class
                        startButton.addClass('resume');

                        // Enable all fields as not recording
                        caseTypeSelect.selectmenu('enable');
                        taskTypeSelect.selectmenu('enable');
                        caseRef.textinput('enable');
                        notes.textinput('enable');
                        findCaseRef.addClass('ui-enabled');

                    }
                }
            },
            errorCB
        );
    }

    // Populate select options from DB
    db.transaction(getCaseTypes, errorCB);
    db.transaction(getTaskTypes, errorCB);

    // Populate the fields with record details
    db.transaction(getRecording, errorCB);
});
```

Also not sure if its relevant but I'm using a multi page template (All #pages in one html document). Thanks again.

Comment: you using local storage?

Comment: @VovaLando Yes, a local websql/phonegap database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the cache:

$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;

You can try to remove specific element from localStorage:

localStorage.removeItem(elementHere);

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using webSQL not localStorage and the cache trick doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the values in an `pagebeforeshow` event handler.

Edit:

You need to orchestrate the SQL transaction and JQM page change.

1) Initiate `pageChange` from within SQL Tx handler

OR

2) Clear existing values in `pagebeforeshow` then initiate SQL Tx. Populate values on screen when available in Tx success callback. You can show a `loading` animation during this wait.

Comment: Yep, I already do that and add the correct values to te fields with the pagebeforeshow event but it still shows the old values for a second or two.

Comment: Since you use websql, I assume you would be populating the fields with new values in the query transaction success callback. Are you clearing the values from screen in the `pagebeforeshow` handler before starting the websql transaction? Would you be able to put up your sample code?

Comment: Hi Yes, I'm clearing the values and running the sql transaction both in the pageeforeshow event - basically I want values to be cleared, and correct values from the db to be on screen before the page is shown to the user. I'll post some sample code up later

Comment: Sample code added - can you see anything that might be amiss? Some of the code will relate to time calculations, ignore this. The issue I'm having is seeing previously viewed values (from the last time #view was displayed) being shown for 1-2 seconds on page load before the current records values get inserted.

Comment: The problem is that the `function(tx,results){...}` is executed `asynchronously` after the SQL `transaction` is completed. JQM would have moved ahead with its page events and transitions by then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - so based on the code in my question and your option 1). should I add $.mobile.changePage... within the Tx success callback? Re your option 2) is this not what I am doing? Or should the SQL Tx be outside of the pagebeforeshow? - any example code would be very helpful, thanks again